# Allow authenticated user to equally access laravel 5.8 default login page

Tags: php, authentication, laravel-5, redirect

I dont know how to go about this. I want a loggedin user in my web app to redirect to the login page without having to logout if they want to.
I have tried adding below code constructor method to `AuthenticatesUser.php` but to no avail.

```php
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth',['only' => ['showLoginForm']]);
}
```

I was also going through the `Route.php` but can't find my way out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In **LoginController** remove the guest middleware

```
public function __construct()
{
    //$this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
}
```

By default **guest** middleware will redirect if the user trying to access the route or method is already autheticated.

Basically only non-logged in users will be able to access the routes or method protected by this middleware.

It uses the **RedirectIfAuthenticated** middleware class so you can modify it to your needs too.